# Has anyone been able to install Ubuntu Server 14.10 on IBM E880 Frame (9119-MHE) (POWER8) on EMC san?

Tags: server, powerpc, ibm

Has anyone been able to install Ubuntu Server 14.04 or 14.10 on IBM E880 Frame (9119-MHE) (POWER8)?

We are using EMC san disk and having issues at the detect disk phase - none of the drivers have worked.  AIX boots properly on this LPAR.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you test with Ubuntu 15.04?

The `ibmvfc` module was just recently added to the installer (See [LP: #1416001](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1416001)).

You can find 15.04 current ISO builds/netboot images at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/

- ISO: /ubuntu-server/daily/current/
- Netboot: /netboot/vivid/

If 15.04 works, please verify that the `ibmvfc` module is being used. 
After the disk detect phase, choose 'Go Back', then 'Execute a shell', and run:

```
lsmod | grep ibmvfc
```

the number should be greater than 0.

If so, please add a comment on that [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1416001), requesting it for 14.04/14.10.

Comment: This did work.  I was able to get past disk detection and was able to install.  The ibmvfc module is being used.  However, multipath does not appear to be functioning, it is still seeing it as separate disks:
root@server:~# pvdisplay
  Found duplicate PV kW8Dc5ErqGfsx16OgNIXkM5YV0PeoBJ1: using /dev/sdd3 not /dev/sdb3

Comment: Cool. Hm. Can you check 'multipath -l'?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that with Little Endian Linux (like the Ubuntu ppc64el images), for official support in PowerVM LPARs, you will need a newer version of Power firmware which is being tested at this time.    This updated FW is expected to be released in the coming months.   The targeted Ubuntu release is 15.04, so testing with that is a good thing to focus on.   The pieces are converging quickly and full support is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu Little Endian on a E880 but its only supported on PowerVM.  Now PowerVM with EMC is a whole another issue.  I have came across a number of issue with PowerVM and EMC (Issue being on the EMC side not IBM. Confirmed by EMC). The links below seam hard to find but should help.  I have no issues with Ubuntu 14.0.4.3 or 15.10.  I am currently running six Ubuntu VMs for PowerVP servers.

Support Links
IBM 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liabu/liabuoverview.htm?lang=en 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamdistros.htm?lang=en

Ubuntu
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/server/models/?vendors=IBM